# I am facing Following build time error in my next.js app with TS

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, build-error

**./app/api/auth/register/route.ts
58:1  Error: `<Document />` from `next/document` should not be imported outside of `pages/_document.js`. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page  @next/next/no-document-import-in-page**

This kind of error I am facing during build time although I have no any file imported _document.js in my API route then why I have this issue?

[It is my project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL7L4.png)

I am using next.js 14.01

Comment: the error seems to indicate that you are importing something from `next/document` inside the `auth/register/route.ts` file. Have you checked it ?